# Some Questions About Covariation Calculation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

When I'm reading "An Introduction to SPDE" by John B. Walsh, I met some problems in the chapter about Stochastic Integrals.

In Page 290, the author defined the covariance measure
$$Q(A,B,(s,t])=<M(A),M(B)>_t-<M(A),M(B)>_s$$
, where M(A), M(B) are all martingales but may not be independent (because it didn't require that $M_t(A)$ is orthogonal martingale measure). Then, he gets the conclusion that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_jQ(A_i,A_j,(s,t]) \ge 0$$
It involves the calculation of covariation process, but I don't know how to get this conclusion.

In Page 294, when he proves Lemma 2.4, he seems to use the conclusion that if $X,Y$ are martingales, then
$$(X_t-X_s)(Y_t-Y_s)-(<X,Y>_t-<X,Y>_s)$$
which is also confusing me.

Can anyone give some related conclusions of covariation?